# phpspreadsheet записать в конец ячейки, сохраняя старые записи ячейки

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Вот так я записываю данные в ячейку `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, $str);`, Как я могу сохранить данные в конец ячейки, не перезаписывая старые данные ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить данные из ячейки. Склеить полученные данные и новое значение и записать результат в ячейку

```
$value = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCellValue('A'.$i);
$value .= $str;
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, $value);
```

Comment: я уже пришел к такому же решению )))
Спасибо, за ответ)